# ember.js model return from API server (POST op) doesn't have an ID in the model store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My REST Api successfully persist a record into the server and return it back to the ember app with an ID. However the ID is not inserted as part of the model in the store. Check out the screen cap

In a controller:

```
var post = this.store.createRecord('post');
post.set('title', this.get('title'));
post.set('author', this.get('author'));
post.set('body', this.get('body'));
post.save(); // => POST to '/posts'
```

Chrome network response from the REST POST. Pardon my writing on the image lol. I hope you guys understand.

[image]

The server JSON response:

```
{"post":
  {"id":"13",
   "title":"i",
   "author":"i",
   "body":"i"
  }
}
```

I don't want to just reload all the data from the server and update the posts table with an ID. What I want is each time a posts is inserted to the server, the table will be dynamically updated with the new entry and with an ID so that it can be viewed as single post in a child view with this route, for example:

```
http://localhost/embercliapp/#/posts/13
```

however after persisting the record to the rest server the URL is this:

```
http://localhost/embercliapp/#/posts/null
```

**UPDATE**

**RESTAdapter**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'api/api-server' //node.js ember mock api
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

posts.hbs

```
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Index</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Author</th>
              <th>Body</th>
              <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {{#each}}
              <tr>
                <td class="id-column">
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{#link-to 'post' this}}
                    {{title}}
                  {{/link-to}}
                </td>
                <td>{{author}}</td>
                <td>{{body}}</td>
                <td><a href="" {{action 'delete' this}}>X</a></td>
              </tr>
            {{/each}}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      {{outlet}}
```

**UPDATE 3**

**router.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
   location: EmberCliAppENV.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('application');                    
  this.resource('posts', function() { //CRUD - read
    //child route
    this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' }); //CRUD - update
    this.resource('new'); //CRUD - create
    this.resource('delete'); //CRUD - delete
  });
  this.route('about');
  this.route('login');  
});

export default Router;
```

Comment: Are you using a custom serializer or adapter?

Comment: I'm using RESTAdapter with ember-cli http-mock REST API

Comment: Is the actual model missing its ID, or is it just the template that is showing a null ID? It's possible that the ID on the model is being set but your template isn't observing the ID properly.

Comment: How do I check that? I only put the model properties in the posts.hbs template. Answer uppdated with posts.hbs

Comment: how do I get the json response from the post.save(), so that I can investigate its ID?

Comment: strange - even though the id is null in the table href link, when I click it, the correct model with an ID is binding in the child view, the correct URL route is shown in the browser URL and the table href is updated with the correct ID

Comment: Can you add your router?

Comment: question updated with route.js

Comment: If you are using the ember inspector ->https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en you can look at the model in it to see whether the id was set correctly.